# Why datepicker does not show up in Rails 3 form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, datepicker

I can't figure out why jQuery datepicker doesn't show up, even though I got jQuery running on my app. Here is what I did:

I got a Rails form that includes

```
  <div id="born_in">
   <%= f.text_field :born_in %><br />
   </div>
```

I included jQuery, jQuery-UI, CSS in head of my application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" %>

<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js",
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

I also have application.js, which shows that my selector is not nil:

```
alert($("#born_in").length)
```

returns 1

I have tried:

```
$("#born_in").datepicker("show")
```

but it doesn't show anything.
So why I don't see datepicker()? Is there a bug with datepicker for this version of jquery-UI? How should I test if this function is included in my app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

was it initialized before hand? as in, did you call

```
$("#born_in").datepicker();
```

some where before that code? if not, you don't need the "show", just run the method with no parameters.

Comment: Hi Kennypu, I did called it in application.js (which is included in head of application.html.erb). But the datepicker doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Rails decides it likes to prepend a form input with the controller name in the id.
For example, my controller name was "Testjqueryui" and in the _form partial, the following (much like yours) was generated:

```
<%= f.text_field :date %>
```

The generated HTML (after the embedded ruby is run) has the id of: "testjqueryui_date".

So, my suggestion would be to check the id of the field that's generated, as it likely has the controller's name prepended.

I put this in the application.js file:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#testjqueryui_date" ).datepicker();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Fishz. I think if you specify <div id = "date"> then jQuery can identify that element correctly (i.e., no need to prefix object's name)

Comment: @AdamNYC: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The <div id="born_in"> in your initial question is unnecessary. The datepicker attaches to a form input (the textbox). The ID of that textbox is what needs to be called in your application.js file. I believe, since you're using the standard rails form helper `<%= f.text_field :born_in %>` that the created text_field will have an id of <Controller>_born_in. Your test, `alert($("#born_in").length) ` is definitely going to return true, since it's targeting the unnecessary div around your field. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I did try the way you suggested $(#my_class_born_in) before I try to explicitly specify div id. Both ways, datepicker doesn't show. :(

Comment: @AdamNYC: Hmmm, that is rather interesting. You're sure the required javascript files are being loaded by the browser?

Comment: Solved it on my end by including `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" >` in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use a jQuery selector to find all the fields that you want displayed as datepickers. One way to do it is to give a particular css class to the datepicker fields, like this:

```
<div id="born_in">
    <%= f.text_field :born_in, :class => "date" %>
</div>
```

And then, in your `application.js` file (or where you want), just write:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.date').datepicker();
});
```

You can also use the id of the particular element instead of a css class. You know the requirements.
Hope this is useful.